# How to initalize PostgreSQL database with schema and tables in script?

Tags: sql, postgresql, docker

I m using Docker container it runs scripts in order 1-db.sql, 2-schemas.sql, 3-tables.sql located in db_init directory

1-db.sql looks like:

```
CREATE DATABASE my_db;
```

2-schemas.sql

```
CREATE SCHEMA my_db.credentials
AUTHORIZATION user1;
```

3-tables.sql

```
CREATE TABLE my_db.credentials."user_credentials"
(
    id integer NOT NULL,
    username character varying(40) NOT NULL,
    password character varying(120) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

Docker command i use (excluding password variables and port mappings) is:

```
docker run --name $CONTAINER_NAME -v $PWD/db_init/:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/ -d -t kartoza/postgis
```

I copy those files to correct directory and they are executed in correct order, however I get messages 'cross-database references are not implemented'
How to specify so that all of that corresponds to same database my_db (it was added to first database gis)?

Comment: `CREATE TABLE my_db.credentials."user_credentials"` The database name is **not** part of the objectname. Only: `schemaname.tablename`

Comment: Yes it was one issue, however after that I got schema and table created in gis database which was created because of the docker container instead of my_db

Comment: OK using \c my_db solved the other issue with switching between schemas